# Binding data to another component and use it in angular using @Input, @Output and EventEmitter

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to pass the one team from array of team in another component and use it. I am getting selected team in same component(team) as console.log but not getting in the another component(team-detail)

Actually, I want to use team id to fetch details of other detail about team from API. please help me around this TIA

Team.component.ts

```
    export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() selectedTeam = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(private general: GeneralService) {
  }

  teamsObject: any;
  teams: [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTeams();
  }

  loadTeams() {
    this.general.getTeams().subscribe(data => {
      this.teamsObject = data;
      this.teams = this.teamsObject.teams;
    });
  }

  onSelectTeam(team: any) {
    this.selectedTeam.emit(team);
  }

}
```

Team.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid " >
<div class="row " >
  <div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let team of teams">
    <div class="card border-dark " style="width: 250px; height: 450px; margin: 10px;" (click)="onSelectTeam(team)">
      <img class="card-img-top embed-responsive" src="{{team.crestUrl}}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{team.name}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{team.address}}</p>
        <a href="{{team.website}}" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Visit Website</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <app-team-detail *ngIf="selectedTeam" [team]="selectedTeam"></app-team-detail>
</div>
```

Team-detail component

```
export class TeamDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() team: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

team-detail template(this template only for demo purpose.)

```
<p>
  {{team.name}}
  {{team.crestUrl}}
  {{team.address}}
  {{team.website}}
</p>
```

Comment: try solution given

Comment: can you create stackblitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Output” identifies the events a component can fire to send information up the hierarchy to its parent. In you case you want to send information from parent component to child. So you don't need to use Output.

Team.component.ts

```
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedTeam:any;

  constructor(private general: GeneralService) {
  }

  teamsObject: any;
  teams: [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadTeams();
  }

  loadTeams() {
    this.general.getTeams().subscribe(data => {
      this.teamsObject = data;
      this.teams = this.teamsObject.teams;
    });
  }

  onSelectTeam(team: any) {
    this.selectedTeam = team;
  }

}
```

team.component.html

```
 <app-team-detail *ngIf="selectedTeam" [team]="selectedTeam"></app-team-detail>
```

team-details template

```
<p *ngIf="team">
  {{team.name}}
  {{team.crestUrl}}
  {{team.address}}
  {{team.website}}
</p>
```

Comment: Not working.. two way data binding doesn’t seems to be right there

Comment: there is no need of two way binding for this

Answer (score 1):

create your property with getter and setter in you child component , rest of code remain as is

```
_team: any;
get team(): any {
    return this._team;
}

@Input()
set team(value: any) {
    this._team = value;
}
```

in child

```
<p *ngIf="team">
  {{team.name}}
  {{team.crestUrl}}
  {{team.address}}
  {{team.website}}
</p>
```